# PDO mySql Connection

Tags: php, mysql

There is [a link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338) that I found a while back. What I would like to know is:

How do I query a simple `SELECT * FROM table_name` using `PDO`?

I tried playing around with the examples here but I was not getting any results back. All along I have been using the `mysql_connect` method which I dont want to use anymore. I would like to use following:

```
<?php 
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
    $username="root";  // Mysql username 
    $password="";      // Mysql password 
    $db_name="microict-intrasys"; // Database name //
    //$id = 5; 

    try { 
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:$host;$db_name,', $username, $password); 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT version FROM system_info'); 
       // $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id)); 
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

        if ( count($result) ) 
        { 
            foreach($result as $row) 
            { 
                print_r($row); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "No rows returned."; 
        } 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    { 
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Great choice leaving out the old mysql_* functions. You should read some of the links @ php manual. http://php.net/pdo there er also examples of use there, even for simple queries like the one you mentioned. For straight out query example see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: I agree with Ronni, you should've looked-up the PHP documentation first before coming here.

Comment: as he finaly postet his source, i think he knows what he is doing but it seems like @user3555680 has a problem with his connection string... see my post below

Comment: Thats what i had tried out above but im still getting "No row returned"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the pdo instance and connect...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourDBName;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

I use `charset` as well to have the correct formated data here... but you dont have to use it. Connection string could also look like

```
PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourDBName" , $username, $password);
```

(using `$username` & `$password` here)

since working with pdo i ran into speed issues when i use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` PDO seems to use the DNS to translate `localhost` into `127.0.0.1` and this causes speed. And im talking about **seconds** just for connecting to DBs

after connecting you can query like

```
$stmt   = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

and than fetch could  results like

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field1'].' '.$row['field2']; //etc...
}
```

or

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

so than you should have at least some result.... **(simple way)**

## I guess your problem is...

accourdig to your source you have a issue in your connectionstring....

```
<?php 
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
    $username="root";  // Mysql username 
    $password="";      // Mysql password 
    $db_name="microict-intrasys"; // Database name 
    //$id = 5; 

    try { 
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}', $username, $password); 
        // you neeeeeed   this--^ and this--^
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT version FROM system_info'); 
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id)); 
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

        if ( count($result) ) 
        { 
            foreach($result as $row) 
            { 
                print_r($row); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "No rows returned."; 
        } 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    { 
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    } 
?>
```

you are missing some in your connection string! kinda **typo**

your parsed string looks like

```
"mysql:localhost;microict-intrasys"
```

and thats wrong. it must look like

```
//"mysql:host=localhost;dbname=microict-intrasys"
"mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=microict-intrasys" // better
```

### PDO Check

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
```

Comment: Please comment out line 6 since this i had got from the example i was trying to use to getting my results. I have changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1 but i am still getting NO RESULT RETURNED. I have corrected what you have mentioned on my question but im still not getting out my result

Comment: @user3555680 does the error says something ? is the connection established ? btw. i also had a lil type in my source... try to copy my connection string again

Comment: @user3555680 is this on a server or do you use this on your local pc ? if its on an server... run pdo check and say whats happening. if nothing is printed, try to use `select * from table` to select all data, you can later break it down to one field